# Use SSRS Date Report Parameter in Access DB Query Where Clause

Tags: sql, ms-access, reporting-services

I have the following query below:

```
SELECT        [File Number], FileNum, [Date Submitted], ReviewDate, ReviewDate2, [50DAY]
FROM            [Site Specific]
WHERE        (ReviewDate2 IS NOT NULL) AND ([Date Submitted] >= @StartDate)
```

And the Where clause I cannot figure out.  The @StartDate is an Report Parameter that is a DateTime variable that has a default value calculated in an expression, but with a calendar picker for rerunning the report.

How do you successfully reference an SSRS report parameter of type DateTime in the where clause of a DataSet's query that runs against an Access Database?

Comment: how are you calling this query?  If as a string with VBA and DAO then wrap @startdate in hashes like: #@StartDate#   if  using the designer then start date works as a parameter :  PARAMETERS [@StartDate] DateTime;
SELECT [Site Specific].[File Number], [Site Specific].FileNum, [Site Specific].[Date Submitted], [Site Specific].ReviewDate, [Site Specific].ReviewDate2, [Site Specific].[50DAY]
FROM [Site Specific]
WHERE ((([Site Specific].[Date Submitted])>=[StartDate]) AND (([Site Specific].ReviewDate2) Is Not Null));  if a combination then consider wrapping startdate in a public function.

Comment: had to remove some @ symbols to post response; pretend like they are there or just delete em all.